# Config module in Nodejs custome environment is not working

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, config

I am using Node JS 14.13.1 and config module version 3.3.6

I made a folder config and inside that, there are two files. config.json and custom-environment-variables.json

inside config.json, I have the following:

```
{
  a:""
}
```

inside custom-environment-variables.json

```
{
 a:"myENV"
}
```

What I see custom-environment-variables never override config.json.

I also set the system environment variable a from windows and also tried with cmd as:

```
set myEnv=myValue
```

I noticed that I need to restart my compute see process.env.myEnv in my node js
but even after restarting and run the app still the value of a is an empty string ( the default.json)

const config=require('config')
config.get('a') // returns empty string rather than shows myValue

Does anyone have this issue?

Thanks

Comment: don't you think your JSON is not correct. It should be
{
  a:""
}

instead of

{
  a=""
}

Comment: Thanks but I think I wrote it wrongly here. In the original set, it was {a:""} and still have the same issue

Comment: Okay when you start the server do you get any warning like no config environment found or something ?

Comment: Okay when you start the server do you get any warning like no config environment found or something ?